# Increment global variables through functions

Tags: python, function, global-variables, return-value, increment

I need increment the variable seed each time the funcion is called, but the output is always the same. Any help?

```
a = 17
c = 43
m = 10000
seed = 13

def randomValue(a,m,c,seed):
    x1=(a*seed+c )%m
    seed = x1
    return (x1/m)

print(randomValue(a,m,c,seed))
print(randomValue(a,m,c,seed))
```

Comment: Please do not edit "Done" into your question. Instead accept or upvote existing answers or create your own answer to report a solution you have found yourself. Maybe write an appreciative comment (you can, even if you do not have the commenting privilege yet).

Answer (score 1):

The [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global-stmt) statements tell the python that within the scope of 
function `randomValue` variable `seed` is referring to the global variable and not the local variable in context of function `randomValue`.

**Replace:**

```
def randomValue(a,m,c,seed):
    x1=(a*seed+c )%m
    seed = x1
    return (x1/m)
```

**With:**

```
def randomValue(a,m,c,seed):
    global seed
    x1=(a*seed+c )%m
    seed = x1
    return (x1/m)
```

---

**To better understand `global` variables consider the following example:**

```
A = 10

def func1():
    print("\nThe value of A inside func1 is:", A)

def func2():
    A = 20
    print("\nThe value of A inside func2 is:", A)

def func3():
    global A
    A = 20
    print("\nThe value of A inside func3 is:", A)

func1()
print("The value of variable A after calling func1 is:", A)

func2()
print("The value of variable A after calling func2 is:", A)

func3()
print("The value of variable A after calling func3 is:", A)
```

**Output:**

```
The value of A inside func1 is: 10
The value of variable A after calling func1 is: 10

The value of A inside func2 is: 20
The value of variable A after calling func2 is: 10

The value of A inside func3 is: 20
The value of variable A after calling func3 is: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with [global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)

```py
a = 17
c = 43
m = 10000
seed = 13


def randomValue():
    global a, m, c, seed
    x1 = (a * seed + c) % m
    seed = x1
    return (x1 / m)


print(randomValue())
print(randomValue())
```